# System.Linq incompatible with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, sqlite

I had a simple two-layer C# solution using `System.Data.OleDb` that did work fine (except for very annoying limitations for the possible SQL commands).

- Upper layer project -> user application that calls methods from the lower layer project
- Lower layer project -> class library that accesses the database

Now I tried to move to `System.Data.SQLite` and something really weird started happening.

I used to have a lot of `IEnuberable<T>.ToList()` methods in the upper layer, coming from `System.Linq` (Which is totally independent from SQLite and was there before adding the SQLite packages).

Now all these `ToList()` methods give me the following error, which doesn't make any sense to me because there is absolutely no `SQLiteDataReader` involved in these `IEnumerable<LotsOfTypes>` instances:

> Error CS0012  The type 'SQLiteDataReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.108.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.

What's going on here? And how can I solve this? Shouldn't the method from `System.Linq` be simply recognized? I really shouldn't need to reference the the SQLite assembly in the upper layer, since it does not access the database.

**Usage example**

```
string[] projectLines = ....;
List<ProjectOld> oldProjects;
IEnumerable<ProjectOld> old  = projectLines.Select(line => new ProjectOld(line));
oldProjects = old.ToList(); //error here!!!
```

**Update**

I actually have an extension method `SQLiteDataReader.ToList()` defined by myself, and if I change this method's name, the error dissapears:

```
public static class DBReaderExtensionsSQLite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// returns a list with the items of type T and closes the reader 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this SQLiteDataReader reader) where T : IDataItem, new()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
            return list;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            T item = new T();
            item.Populate(reader);
            list.Add(item);
        }

        reader.Close();
        return list;
    }
```

But, still something pretty wrong here, since I had this same method with `OleDbDataReader` and nothing wrong happened:

```
public static class DBReaderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// returns a list with the items of type T and closes the reader 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this OleDbDataReader reader) where T : IDataItem, new()
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
            return list;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            T item = new T();
            item.Populate(reader);
            list.Add(item);
        }

        reader.Close();
        return list;
    }
```

Why would this happen only with `SQLiteDataReader` and not with `OleDbDataReader`??

Comment: Are you sure those aren't `IQueryable<T>.ToList()` calls?

Comment: Wouldn't these three lines be enough to assure `IEnumerable`? --> `List<ProjectOld> oldProjects;` / `IEnumerable<ProjectOld> old  = projectLines.Select(line => new ProjectOld(line));` / `oldProjects = old.ToList();` --- Here, `projectLines` is `string[]`.

Comment: Is there a way to select from which library I want the extension method to be used?

Comment: It's determined based on the underlying type.  An `IQueryable` is going to generate SQL and run it against a DB where as `IEnumerable` is just going to run the Linq in memory.  In this case it does look like the latter and I can only guess the error is mentioned at that point if `ProjectOld` is an entity.  But ultimately the fix is just to add the appropriate reference.

Comment: ProjectOld is a totally custom class that implements totally custom interfaces.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is the right `ToList` that is being called? eg click "Go to definition" on it and confirm that it is definitely running `Enumerable.ToList`.

Comment: Yes it is.... I'm posting some updates to the question as I find out things...

Comment: The "go to definition" points to an "Enumerable" file. And the cause of the problem is a method with same name created by me, but still it behaves weirdly.

Comment: I'm not really sure either. What I'm wondering is if when the compiler is trying to get the candidate list for your extension method whether it finds your `ToList` for `SQLiteDataReader` and wants to know more but can't find out any more because there is no reference to it. It therefore can't work out whether ToList is a valid extension method here and thus errors. Its the best I can think of...

Comment: I already got this error message `XXX is defined in an assembly that is not referenced` (where `XXX` is the some assembly) with other assemblies such as `NHibernate`. Just to try it out, add the reference on SQLite provider on the `Upper` project.

Comment: What does `new ProjectOld(line)` do?

Comment: It's the object creator. It just takes the `string line` and populates itself.